# How to create 80MHz hotspot with NetworkManager on linux?

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot, bandwidth

My OS is Archlinux and onboard wifi chip is `MediaTek MT7921` which is a wifi-6 chip. According to [this wiki](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/PCIe_WiFi_Devices.md) MT7921 supports creating 80MHz hotspot on linux.

I use command `nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid TestWifi password TestPassword ifname wlp6s0 band a channel 165` to create a hotspot. However, scanning it using wifi scanner app on android shows that it only has 20MHz, which is unacceptably slow according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1619103).

So how to apply 40MHz/80MHz bandwidth to NetworkManager configuration? I cannot find any config option of this from [official documentation](https://networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/NetworkManager.conf.html).

BTW if NetworkManager isn't capable of doing this, is there any other easy tool on linux to create hotspot with specified bandwidth?

The command `iw phy phy0 info` shows the detail of this chip:

```
Wiphy phy0
        wiphy index: 0
        max # scan SSIDs: 4
        max scan IEs length: 482 bytes
        max # sched scan SSIDs: 10
        max # match sets: 16
        Retry short limit: 7
        Retry long limit: 4
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
        Device supports T-DLS.
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
                * CCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:10)
                * GCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:8)
                * GCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:9)
                * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
                * CMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:13)
                * GMAC-128 (00-0f-ac:11)
                * GMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:12)
        Available Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
        Configured Antennas: TX 0x3 RX 0x3
        Supported interface modes:
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
        Band 1:
                Capabilities: 0x9ff
                        RX LDPC
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX Greenfield
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
                        No DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: No restriction (0x00)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
                HE Iftypes: managed
                        HE MAC Capabilities (0x08011a000040):
                                +HTC HE Supported
                                Trigger Frame MAC Padding Duration: 2
                                OM Control
                                Maximum A-MPDU Length Exponent: 3
                                A-MSDU in A-MPDU
                        HE PHY Capabilities: (0x2270ce120dc0b306423f00):
                                HE40/2.4GHz
                                242 tone RUs/2.4GHz
                                Device Class: 1
                                LDPC Coding in Payload
                                HE SU PPDU with 1x HE-LTF and 0.8us GI
                                NDP with 4x HE-LTF and 3.2us GI
                                STBC Tx <= 80MHz
                                STBC Rx <= 80MHz
                                Full Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                Partial Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                DCM Max Constellation: 2
                                DCM Max Constellation Rx: 2
                                SU Beamformee
                                Beamformee STS <= 80Mhz: 3
                                Ng = 16 SU Feedback
                                Ng = 16 MU Feedback
                                Codebook Size SU Feedback
                                Codebook Size MU Feedback
                                Triggered CQI Feedback
                                Partial Bandwidth Extended Range
                                PPE Threshold Present
                                Power Boost Factor ar
                                HE SU PPDU & HE PPDU 4x HE-LTF 0.8us GI
                                20MHz in 40MHz HE PPDU 2.4GHz
                                DCM Max BW: 1
                                Longer Than 16HE SIG-B OFDM Symbols
                                Non-Triggered CQI Feedback
                                TX 1024-QAM
                                RX 1024-QAM
                                RX Full BW SU Using HE MU PPDU with Compression SIGB
                                RX Full BW SU Using HE MU PPDU with Non-Compression SIGB
                        HE RX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        HE TX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        PPE Threshold 0x39 0x1c 0xc7 0x71 0x1c 0x07 
                EHT Iftypes: managed
                        EHT MAC Capabilities (0x0000):
                        EHT PHY Capabilities: (0x0000000000000000):
                        EHT MCS/NSS: (0x):
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 0-7: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 8-9: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 10-11: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 12-13: Rx=0, Tx=0
                HE Iftypes: AP
                        HE MAC Capabilities (0x00011a081044):
                                +HTC HE Supported
                                BSR
                                OM Control
                                Maximum A-MPDU Length Exponent: 3
                                BQR
                                A-MSDU in A-MPDU
                                OM Control UL MU Data Disable RX
                        HE PHY Capabilities: (0x0220ce120000a000000c00):
                                HE40/2.4GHz
                                LDPC Coding in Payload
                                NDP with 4x HE-LTF and 3.2us GI
                                STBC Tx <= 80MHz
                                STBC Rx <= 80MHz
                                Full Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                Partial Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                DCM Max Constellation: 2
                                DCM Max Constellation Rx: 2
                                Partial Bandwidth Extended Range
                                PPE Threshold Present
                                TX 1024-QAM
                                RX 1024-QAM
                        HE RX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        HE TX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        PPE Threshold 0x39 0x1c 0xc7 0x71 0x1c 0x07 
                EHT Iftypes: AP
                        EHT MAC Capabilities (0x0000):
                        EHT PHY Capabilities: (0x0000000000000000):
                        EHT MCS/NSS: (0x):
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 0-7: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 8-9: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 10-11: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw=20 MHz, max NSS for MCS 12-13: Rx=0, Tx=0
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 1.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
        Band 2:
                Capabilities: 0x9ff
                        RX LDPC
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX Greenfield
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
                        No DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: No restriction (0x00)
                HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
                VHT Capabilities (0x339071b2):
                        Max MPDU length: 11454
                        Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
                        RX LDPC
                        short GI (80 MHz)
                        TX STBC
                        SU Beamformee
                        MU Beamformee
                        RX antenna pattern consistency
                        TX antenna pattern consistency
                VHT RX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: MCS 0-9
                        3 streams: not supported
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
                VHT TX MCS set:
                        1 streams: MCS 0-9
                        2 streams: MCS 0-9
                        3 streams: not supported
                        4 streams: not supported
                        5 streams: not supported
                        6 streams: not supported
                        7 streams: not supported
                        8 streams: not supported
                VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
                VHT extended NSS: supported
                HE Iftypes: managed
                        HE MAC Capabilities (0x08011a000040):
                                +HTC HE Supported
                                Trigger Frame MAC Padding Duration: 2
                                OM Control
                                Maximum A-MPDU Length Exponent: 3
                                A-MSDU in A-MPDU
                        HE PHY Capabilities: (0x4470ce120dc0b306423f00):
                                HE40/HE80/5GHz
                                242 tone RUs/5GHz
                                Device Class: 1
                                LDPC Coding in Payload
                                HE SU PPDU with 1x HE-LTF and 0.8us GI
                                NDP with 4x HE-LTF and 3.2us GI
                                STBC Tx <= 80MHz
                                STBC Rx <= 80MHz
                                Full Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                Partial Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                DCM Max Constellation: 2
                                DCM Max Constellation Rx: 2
                                SU Beamformee
                                Beamformee STS <= 80Mhz: 3
                                Ng = 16 SU Feedback
                                Ng = 16 MU Feedback
                                Codebook Size SU Feedback
                                Codebook Size MU Feedback
                                Triggered CQI Feedback
                                Partial Bandwidth Extended Range
                                PPE Threshold Present
                                Power Boost Factor ar
                                HE SU PPDU & HE PPDU 4x HE-LTF 0.8us GI
                                20MHz in 40MHz HE PPDU 2.4GHz
                                DCM Max BW: 1
                                Longer Than 16HE SIG-B OFDM Symbols
                                Non-Triggered CQI Feedback
                                TX 1024-QAM
                                RX 1024-QAM
                                RX Full BW SU Using HE MU PPDU with Compression SIGB
                                RX Full BW SU Using HE MU PPDU with Non-Compression SIGB
                        HE RX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        HE TX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        PPE Threshold 0x39 0x1c 0xc7 0x71 0x1c 0x07 
                EHT Iftypes: managed
                        EHT MAC Capabilities (0x0000):
                        EHT PHY Capabilities: (0x0000000000000000):
                        EHT MCS/NSS: (0x):
                        EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 8-9: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 10-11: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 12-13: Rx=0, Tx=0
                HE Iftypes: AP
                        HE MAC Capabilities (0x00011a081044):
                                +HTC HE Supported
                                BSR
                                OM Control
                                Maximum A-MPDU Length Exponent: 3
                                BQR
                                A-MSDU in A-MPDU
                                OM Control UL MU Data Disable RX
                        HE PHY Capabilities: (0x0420ce120000a000000c00):
                                HE40/HE80/5GHz
                                LDPC Coding in Payload
                                NDP with 4x HE-LTF and 3.2us GI
                                STBC Tx <= 80MHz
                                STBC Rx <= 80MHz
                                Full Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                Partial Bandwidth UL MU-MIMO
                                DCM Max Constellation: 2
                                DCM Max Constellation Rx: 2
                                Partial Bandwidth Extended Range
                                PPE Threshold Present
                                TX 1024-QAM
                                RX 1024-QAM
                        HE RX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        HE TX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                                3 streams: not supported
                                4 streams: not supported
                                5 streams: not supported
                                6 streams: not supported
                                7 streams: not supported
                                8 streams: not supported
                        PPE Threshold 0x39 0x1c 0xc7 0x71 0x1c 0x07 
                EHT Iftypes: AP
                        EHT MAC Capabilities (0x0000):
                        EHT PHY Capabilities: (0x0000000000000000):
                        EHT MCS/NSS: (0x):
                        EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 8-9: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 10-11: Rx=0, Tx=0
                        EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 12-13: Rx=0, Tx=0
                Bitrates (non-HT):
                        * 6.0 Mbps
                        * 9.0 Mbps
                        * 12.0 Mbps
                        * 18.0 Mbps
                        * 24.0 Mbps
                        * 36.0 Mbps
                        * 48.0 Mbps
                        * 54.0 Mbps
                Frequencies:
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5720 MHz [144] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm)
                        * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
                        * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
        Supported commands:
                 * new_interface
                 * set_interface
                 * new_key
                 * start_ap
                 * new_station
                 * new_mpath
                 * set_mesh_config
                 * set_bss
                 * authenticate
                 * associate
                 * deauthenticate
                 * disassociate
                 * join_ibss
                 * join_mesh
                 * remain_on_channel
                 * set_tx_bitrate_mask
                 * frame
                 * frame_wait_cancel
                 * set_wiphy_netns
                 * set_channel
                 * tdls_mgmt
                 * tdls_oper
                 * start_sched_scan
                 * probe_client
                 * set_noack_map
                 * register_beacons
                 * start_p2p_device
                 * set_mcast_rate
                 * connect
                 * disconnect
                 * channel_switch
                 * set_qos_map
                 * set_multicast_to_unicast
                 * set_sar_specs
        WoWLAN support:
                 * wake up on disconnect
                 * wake up on magic packet
                 * wake up on pattern match, up to 1 patterns of 1-128 bytes,
                   maximum packet offset 0 bytes
                 * can do GTK rekeying
                 * wake up on network detection, up to 10 match sets
        software interface modes (can always be added):
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed, P2P-client } <= 2, #{ AP, P2P-GO } <= 1,
                   total <= 2, #channels <= 2
        HT Capability overrides:
                 * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
                 * maximum A-MSDU length
                 * supported channel width
                 * short GI for 40 MHz
                 * max A-MPDU length exponent
                 * min MPDU start spacing
        Device supports TX status socket option.
        Device supports HT-IBSS.
        Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
        Device supports scan flush.
        Device supports per-vif TX power setting
        Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
        Driver supports a userspace MPM
        Device supports active monitor (which will ACK incoming frames)
        Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
        Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
        Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in scans.
        Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
        max # scan plans: 1
        max scan plan interval: 65535
        max scan plan iterations: 0
        Supported TX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
                 * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
        Supported RX frame types:
                 * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * managed: 0x40 0xb0 0xd0
                 * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
                 * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
                 * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
        Supported extended features:
                * [ RRM ]: RRM
                * [ SET_SCAN_DWELL ]: scan dwell setting
                * [ BEACON_RATE_LEGACY ]: legacy beacon rate setting
                * [ BEACON_RATE_HT ]: HT beacon rate setting
                * [ BEACON_RATE_VHT ]: VHT beacon rate setting
                * [ FILS_STA ]: STA FILS (Fast Initial Link Setup)
                * [ CQM_RSSI_LIST ]: multiple CQM_RSSI_THOLD records
                * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211 ]: control port over nl80211
                * [ ACK_SIGNAL_SUPPORT ]: ack signal level support
                * [ TXQS ]: FQ-CoDel-enabled intermediate TXQs
                * [ CAN_REPLACE_PTK0 ]: can safely replace PTK 0 when rekeying
                * [ AIRTIME_FAIRNESS ]: airtime fairness scheduling
                * [ AQL ]: Airtime Queue Limits (AQL)
                * [ CONTROL_PORT_NO_PREAUTH ]: disable pre-auth over nl80211 control port support
                * [ SCAN_FREQ_KHZ ]: scan on kHz frequency support
                * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211_TX_STATUS ]: tx status for nl80211 control port support
                * [ BEACON_RATE_HE ]: HE beacon rate support (AP/mesh)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be operating as intended.  Channel 165 is a 20MHz channel, as you see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#5_GHz_(802.11a/h/n/ac/ax).  The channels you seek are listed under the column 40MHz and 80MHz in Wikipedia.

You helpfully included the iw output so this information is right there.  Look at Band2 under Frequencies.  The channels [in square brackets] are all 20MHz channels.  In fact there are painfully few choices.  :-(

So, in short, your hardware will not support more than 20MHz.